# Client error when setting a TSQL trigger: Record not found or changed by another user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to set a trigger that generates a txt file after an insert statment. So far, so good, and the code works fine when I run it in SQL Studio, But when I insert a row from the Client UI (a software called A3ERP) the following error appears:

*Record not found or changed by another user*

Then the file is generated but the **table doesn't insert the new row**.

Here is the code for the trigger:

```
USE [BUSINESS]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_COMUNIDAD_TEST]
   ON  [dbo].[COMUNIDAD] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo tesline > D:\Datos\Comun\AriesAuto\comunidad_testfile.txt'
END
```

Any suggestions? I'm stuck in this error.

Thank you.

Comment: This logic honestly has no right being in SQL Server, let alone in a trigger. I strongly suggest you move the logic to the application.

Comment: This is a likely big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But the problem lies within your application code / development environment. And a warning - changing the schema of a licensed system is generally considered a violation of that license.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` in a trigger is just the epitome of bad. Why would you want to do this? I'm guessing `xp_cmdshell` is returning resultsets and confusing the client

Comment: Thanks everyone. Looks like my approach from SQL Server is wrong, as @Larnu says I will try to move the logic to the application.

Comment: @Charlieface, can you elaborate a little more why? Stating the obvious: I'm not a programmer, but I would like to know as it seemed right to me.

Comment: @SMor, thanks for the comment. The X would be that I'm trying to automate the generation of a file when some actions occurs inside an ERP software based on SQL.

Comment: Because triggers run inside transactions, and should be short and only access the database, not outside resources, otherwise you risk causing errors (which cause rollback) or blocking (which causes the application to wait). And `xp_cmdshell` is anyway a bit of hack: T-SQL is not a generalized scripting langauge, you shouldn't use it as such.

Comment: Did you see anything in the event logs? How about Sql Logs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

As @Charlieface point out, the error was caused by a string of text that xp_cmdshell was returning to the client. Adding the argument [ , no_output ] solved it:

```
USE [BUSINESS]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_COMUNIDAD_TEST]
   ON  [dbo].[COMUNIDAD] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo tesline > D:\Datos\Comun\AriesAuto\comunidad_testfile.txt',no_output
END
```

Also, as everyone seems to agree: this logic should be in the application and not on the SQL Server, but as I didn't write the application and I have no means to implement things there, this solution works for me. Thanks everyone!